# Responsive flat CSS tree menu with icons, bend connectors and hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, tree, responsive-design

I have a problem stylizing a CSS tree menu with connectors and categories named as icons + text (can be squares). There might be some tooltip or modal window with a short description. The code I'm trying to get it work is this one: [tree menu](http://codepen.io/Pestov/pen/BLpgm)

The goal is this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAJjZ.png

Anybody knows how to bend those connectors and connect them so they are even responsive? Is it evne possible with only CSS?

Comment: I'm 99,9% sure you can't achieve this only with CSS, you'll need some JS.

Comment: I'm trying to minimize the use of JS but for such reason I'd be ok even with that.

Comment: You just have to find all parents of an element:hover with JS, that will be very light.